# Is there something similar to NanoBSD in Linux

Tags: linux, embedded, linux-kernel, freebsd, embedded-linux

NanoBSD is a script that makes light, small and in-memory FreeBSD copy. It is useful in embedded systems. Is there something similar to NanoBSD in Linux? Specially a feature like `Everything is read-only at run-time` as it mentioned [here](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/nanobsd/index.html) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of toolchain / system build systems build Linux root filesystems which are designed to run completely out of a ramdisc (rootfs / tmpfs). This means that everything is read/write at runtime, but it does not persist across reboots (a persistent FS can of course, be mounted as a non-root FS).

The most well known of these is Busybox (with or without uclibc), which ships with various scripts to build very small-footprint Linux-based embedded systems (root FS is typically a few Mb only; just add a kernel). Busybox/Linux is not the same as GNU/Linux, but it is fairly similar - most things are simpler or have fewer options; some features are entirely absent or can be disabled at compile-time.

Linux is NOT an Operating system like FreeBSD, rather it is a kernel. You can choose to layer either GNU C library and tools (which I think all major general-purpose distributions do) or something else - which is mostly used for smaller systems, including uclibc, Android etc.

Answer (score 5):

There are literally hundreds of toolchains, build environments and embedded distros of Linux, some only a couple of megabytes in size.  Many also support some or many of the different processors Linux runs on (i386 and friends, ARM, Power, ...).

To get you started a couple of projects I find interesting: [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/) and [OpenEmbedded](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Main_Page), and [lpclinux](http://www.lpclinux.com/), Linux for NXP LPC3xxx ARM processors but there are really hundreds of them.

#### Some other resources

A very good source that (also) touches a number of issues specific to embedded systems is [Linux from scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/).  And [this pdf](http://elinux.org/images/b/b1/Filesystems-for-embedded-linux.pdf) gives some insight in the different available filesystems for an embedded Linux system.

Comment: Any one of systems you referred does `Everything is read-only at run-time` which means few frequent access to the Compact Flash or Hard Disk.

Comment: @adban yes, it's entirely possible to setup a Linux system with a ro root filesystem (google squashfs).  If the system needs to have some writeable space that's often solved with a RAM disk, or some (in that case writeable) flash storage.  Some embedded systems even run entirely out of RAM disk - the flash-stored root is loaded in a RAM disk and after that the flash isn't touched anymore.

Comment: Yes thank you very much about all these inf and resources, but I am not asking about the possibility of such system as I am asking about the availability. NanoBSD has flexibility to customize easly and install what software we actually need and then use it in Soekris board, for example.

Comment: @Adban there are several blogs and forums that describe how to use eg OpenWRT on Soekris hardware.  I pointed to some backgrounders because in this kind of systems just knowing how to kickstart a "ready to run" image is a very dangerous approach...

Answer (score 1):

i would take a look at TinyCore-Linux.
which isn't really ro but nearly the same Concept and i think there is also a was to get the OS/Binary Part ro were the config part is writeable.

Comment: Place this edit as part of your post, not a comment.